# MVC3 Best solution to manage multiple lookup tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having hard time to find the right solution to manage multiple modificable lookup tables (more than 40), most of them with the same structure. I'm using the repository approach but I can't make it work. Has someone a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my repository pattern for EF4.1/4.2 it allows you to easially connect to an EF4.1 DB and query it throughout your solution.

http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/10/staticvoid-repository-pattern-nuget.html

a working source application is also available here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37129059/StaticVoid.Repository.Demo.zip

Answer (score 0):

A tool that worked great for me is a t4 code generation template that generates enums out of lookup tables. It can save you a lot of work and keep your source code up to date when you add some new items to the look up tables.

I also use a DB with ~30 lookup tables and it was easy to set up, modify and use (even though I did not knew much about t4 templates before).

http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html

Comment: Do you have any test project where you've implemented this? Just to have a clear idea on how practical it is.